# Convert JSON to list of objects

Tags: c#, json, json.net, data-conversion

I have defined a `Quote` class like this:

```
public class Quote
{
    public double Price { get; set; }
    public string Symbol { get; set; }
}
```

The following JSON is returned by a Web API rest endpoint and does not include an explicit `symbol` field.  The symbols are the named objects, e.g. `AAPL`, `GOOG`, `FB`:

```
{                       
    "AAPL": {           
        "price": 205    
    },                  
    "GOOG": {           
        "price": 1230.38
    },                  
    "FB": {             
        "price": 178.41 
    }                   
}
```

What is the best way to convert this JSON to a `List<Quote>`?

Comment: Where is the `symbol` in you json?

Comment: The json doesn't explicitly have a "symbol" field, that's the tricky part.

Comment: So where this `symbol` comes from to assign it to `Symbol` property in your class while deserialization

Comment: `Quote.Symbol` is the stock ticker, e.g. `AAPL` `GOOG` `FB`

Comment: Where is this json object defined? any local file or is it just a string, than you want to convert to json for this `Quote` class?

Comment: json is retrieved from web api rest endpoint

Comment: Is there is restriction to use class `Quote`? or any else type will be accepted to you?

Comment: no restrictions - I could introduce an intermediate type and post-deserialization then convert it to `Quote`

Comment: @BaltoStar, I added my answer below, try it and let me know :)

Comment: Small recommendation - you perhaps would be better served using `decimal` instead of `double` for the price.

Answer (score 3):

One simple approach to deal with your tricky part of json

1) Deserialize your json to `Dictionary<string, dynamic>`.

2) Then flatten your dictionary result to `List<Quote>`.

```
string json = File.ReadAllText(@"Path to your json");

List<Quote> quotes = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, dynamic>>(json)
    .Select(x => new Quote
    {
        Symbol = x.Key,
        Price = x.Value.price    //<= x.Value is dynamic type so you can access your key with dot(.) separator
    })
    .ToList();


//-------------Print the result to Console-------------

Console.WriteLine("Symbol\tPrice");
Console.WriteLine("----------------------");
foreach (var quote in quotes)
{
    Console.WriteLine(quote.Symbol +"\t" + quote.Price);
}
```

**Alternative:**

You can use `JToken` instead of `dynamic`,

```
List<Quote> quotes = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, JToken>>(json)
    .Select(x => new Quote
    {
        Symbol = x.Key,
        Price = Convert.ToDouble(x.Value["price"])
    })
    .ToList();
```

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: That's much simpler. I want to know , is it applicable to xml format?

Comment: @its4zahoor, Yes if you would like to use xml with `XDocument`. Because `XDocument` support LINQ and with LINQ you can flatten your result to whatever you want :)

Comment: ah right i forgot about dynamic - used this years ago. but VS is giving me a method not found error for `.Select` - any idea why ?

Comment: @BaltoStar, Add this namespace to top of your program => `using System.Linq;`

Comment: @BaltoStar, What happen? Does it work for you? If yes then please mark the tick on left side of answer to make it green :)

Comment: how to force `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject()` to not attempt to set types for the `dynamic` member fields ?  if you drill into `Dictionary<string,dynamic>` you can see that for each `dynamic` `KeyValuePair` value type it's converting to `int` `decimal` `DateTime` on some best-match basis algo. i'd rather it leave them as strings and then I parse each individually

Comment: @BaltoStar, you mean `JsonConvert` to parse type `string` for any `dynamic` fields and later you can explicitly convert it to appropriate type that you want like `int`, `decimal` or any else, m i right? You can try code in **Alternative** section, in that `JToken` can does what you want. IMO `JToken` is best suited for you and its best option than `dynamic`. You can parse `JToken` to any type that you want. And that's why I'd privide you alternative option also :)

Comment: @BaltoStar, I think you forgot to give me reply! what happened? Did you face any problem now?

Answer (score 2):

You could make a custom [`JsonConverter`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonConverter.htm) to convert this JSON structure into the `List<Quote>` format you want.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;

public class QuoteListConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return objectType == typeof(List<Quote>);
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        JObject obj = JObject.Load(reader);
        return obj.Properties()
                  .Select(p => new Quote
                  {
                      Symbol = p.Name,
                      Price = p.Value["price"].ToObject<double>()
                  })
                  .ToList();
    }

    public override bool CanWrite
    {
        get { return false; }
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Then use it like this:

```
var quotes = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json, new QuoteListConverter());
```

Working demo: https://dotnetfiddle.net/kcU8DO